# Integration testing with spring declarative caching

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, caching, integration-testing

I'm trying to write integration tests for a Spring Boot 2 Application.

One test should test updating a value via REST.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager
@Transactional
public class TenantEndpointIT {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void nok_updateValueForbidden() {

    }
}
```

Now, I thought the cleanest way was to create the value with the `TestEntityManager` in the @Before method, then test the REST endpoint in the actual test.

**But** the service called by the REST Endpoint is annotated with Spring Caching annotations. So the test fails if I do that. I could use the service directly or make a second REST call. That creates problems with other tests using the same Value, because even if the DB is rolled-back, the cache seems to contain the value. (Now I'm using @DirtiesContext).

My question is, how do you correctly integration test services with @Cachable?
Is there a way to get the Cache and explicitly put/remove?
I tried autowiring a CacheManager, but it won't find one and fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add `@AutoConfigureCache` on your test, it will override whatever cache strategies you've defined in your app by a `CacheManager` that noops. That's pretty useful if you want to make sure that cache doesn't interfere with your tests.